# How to install new Laravel package without updating other packages while the project are missing lock file

Tags: php, laravel

I need to install new Laravel package via composer but the project missing lock file.If I could add lock file via composer install but it update all packages which I don't want that, what I need is to install new package without updates the old one. I read various old option but does not work.

Comment: "How to solve this?" Install [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) first.

Comment: Actually you haven't installed the composer on your live server yet. That's why you are getting that output.

Comment: Did you restart your terminal?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I thinks the composer installed successful. All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer (version 2.0.9) successfully installed to: /home/career/example.com/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar @Tpojka